# How to changes or update local server connection in Maintenance plan job

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, jobs, maintenance

Two days back our client changed one of our Dev Server name

After Server Renamed, All my maintenance jobs and other jobs are failing because server name mismatch.

We are using **sql server 2012** version and **server 2008 OS**

So today morning i renamed my Sql server 2012 name to updated given name and made table, procedures updates

I tried to update Local server connection in maintenance job but it is uneditable.
Then i added new server connection,still no use i am getting below error, while executing jobs.

After i tried with target page in jobs property option, there also only target server is selected and multiple target server is disable.

**Error below**

Executed as user: 
NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. 
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Started:  12:01:28 AM  Error: 2013-12-16 00:01:43.98     Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: {410F7661-F71A-4B68-9584-BA422AB00F02} Execute SQL Task
Description: Failed to acquire connection "Local server connection". 
Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error
Error: 2013-12-16 00:02:00.00
Code: 0xC0024104
Source: Territory_Update
Description: The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131904 
(A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)). 
The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.  End Error
Error: 2013-12-16 00:02:15.00
Code: 0xC0024104
Source: {4E2AF328-0B8D-4905-83BE-839FDDEFC09C}
Description: The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131904 
(A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)). 
The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.
End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  12:01:28 AM
Finished: 12:02:15 AM
Elapsed:  46.641 seconds.
The package execution failed.
The step failed.

Help me out in this guys, Thanks in advance

Comment: I got the same issue. Recreated maintenance plan.

Answer (score 16):

Maintenance plans make use of SSIS packages that are stored in MSDB. These packages use connection strings, which are not changed after a server rename.

Use the script (reproduced below) posted by [NancySon](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/nancyson/) in the comments of [How to: Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799%28SQL.100%29.aspx) to get some inspiration on how to change these connection strings. Or recreate the maintenance plans.

> Maintenance plans don't get their connections changed to the new server name and so they may break. After a rename you may find that you cannot delete or rename the existing maintenance plans, so either delete them before renaming the server and recreate them afterwards or run the following script to fix them:
>
> ```
>    use msdb
>
>    DECLARE @oldservername as varchar(max)
>     SET @oldservername='<server name>\<instance name>'
>
>    -- set the new server name to the current server name
>
>    declare @newservername as varchar(max)
>     set @newservername=@@servername
>
>    declare @xml as varchar(max)
>     declare @packagedata as varbinary(max)
>     -- get all the plans that have the old server name in their connection string
>     DECLARE PlansToFix Cursor
>     FOR
>     SELECT    id
>     FROM         sysssispackages
>     WHERE     (CAST(CAST(packagedata AS varbinary(MAX)) AS varchar(MAX)) LIKE '%server=''' + @oldservername + '%')
>
>    OPEN PlansToFix
>
>
>    declare @planid uniqueidentifier
>     fetch next from PlansToFix into @planid
>
>    while (@@fetch_status<>-1)  -- for each plan
>
>    begin
>     if (@@fetch_status<>-2)
>     begin
>     select @xml=cast(cast(packagedata as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) from sysssispackages where id= @planid  -- get the plan's xml converted to an xml string
>
>    declare @planname varchar(max)
>     select @planname=[name] from  sysssispackages where id= @planid  -- get the plan name
>     print 'Changing ' + @planname + ' server from ' + @oldservername + ' to ' + @newservername  -- print out what change is happening
>
>    set @xml=replace(@xml,'server=''' + @oldservername + '''','server=''' + @newservername +'''')  -- replace the old server name with the new server name in the connection string
>     select @packagedata=cast(@xml as varbinary(max))  -- convert the xml back to binary
>     UPDATE    sysssispackages SET packagedata = @packagedata WHERE (id= @planid)  -- update the plan
>
>    end
>     fetch next from PlansToFix into @planid  -- get the next plan
>
>    end
>
>    close PlansToFix
>     deallocate PlansToFix
> ```

> ```
>   ----- This will also handle the packages that have a tag such as 
>     ----- <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=servername;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;</DTS:Property>
>
>
>
>    DECLARE @oldservername as varchar(max)
>     SET @oldservername='<server name>\<instance name>'-- set the new server name to the current server name
>     declare @newservername as varchar(max)
>     set @newservername = @@servername
>     declare @xml as varchar(max)
>     declare @packagedata as varbinary(max)-- get all the plans that have the old server name in their connection string
>     DECLARE PlansToFix Cursor FOR 
>     SELECT id
>     FROM sysssispackages
>     WHERE (CAST(CAST(packagedata AS varbinary(MAX)) AS varchar(MAX)) LIKE '%Data Source=' + @oldservername + '%')
>
>    OPEN PlansToFix
>     declare @planid uniqueidentifier
>     fetch next from PlansToFix into @planid 
>     while (@@fetch_status<>-1) -- for each plan 
>     begin
>     if (@@fetch_status<>-2)
>     begin
>     select @xml=cast(cast(packagedata as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) 
>     from sysssispackages where id= @planid -- get the plan's xml converted to an xml string
>     declare @planname varchar(max)select @planname=[name] from sysssispackages where id= @planid -- get the plan name
>     print 'Changing ' + @planname + ' server from ' + @oldservername + ' to ' + @newservername -- print out what change is happening
>     set @xml=replace(@xml,'Data Source=' + @oldservername,'Data Source=' + @newservername) -- replace the old server name with the new server name in the connection string
>     select @packagedata=cast(@xml as varbinary(max)) -- convert the xml back to binary
>     UPDATE sysssispackages SET packagedata = @packagedata WHERE (id= @planid) -- update the plan
>     end
>     fetch next from PlansToFix into @planid -- get the next plan
>     end
>     close PlansToFix
>     deallocate PlansToFix
> ```

Answer (score 6):

I used this code from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/699806) to the Server Fault question [Renamed a SQL Server, however maintenance plans still have old name](https://serverfault.com/q/289995):

```
SELECT  x.*,
        LocalServerConnectionString = cm.value('declare namespace DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";DTS:ObjectData[1]/DTS:ConnectionManager[1]/@DTS:ConnectionString', 'varchar(1000)')
FROM (
    SELECT  id, name, packageXML = CAST(CAST(packagedata AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML)
    FROM dbo.sysssispackages
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.sysmaintplan_plans)
) x
CROSS APPLY packageXML.nodes('declare namespace DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";/DTS:Executable/DTS:ConnectionManagers/DTS:ConnectionManager[@DTS:ObjectName="Local server connection"]') p(cm)
```

And to rename:

```
UPDATE dbo.sysssispackages SET packagedata = CAST(CAST(REPLACE(CAST(CAST(packagedata AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'OldServerName', 'NewServerName') AS XML) AS VARBINARY(MAX))
WHERE id = 'package GUID'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you rename an SQL Server (i.e. change the Windows NetBIOS name), you also need to carry out this small manual step inside SQL Server to rename it internally. Details in [this MSKB article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread/question but had a similar problem today and solved it by applying the scripts above, so thank you @AhsenB. And in the process i found another way of solving this: edit the step in the job, under Data sources, check Local server connection and edit the Data Source=Servername part. And voila!